# How to implement command pattern in the newest versions of ReactiveUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reactiveui, command-pattern

I'm following the sample that given from the official GitHub page about using ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand below. (ReactiveUI v8.0.1) [github link](https://github.com/Asesjix/ReactiveUI.Winforms.Samples/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Winforms.Samples.Commands/ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs)

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveCommand ParameterlessCommand { get; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ParameterlessCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(Parameterless);
    }


    private void Parameterless()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The errors occur when I use this implementation with the ReactiveUI v13.0.38
[image]

1. The first error is "*CS0722 'ReactiveCommand': static types cannot
   be used as return types*".
2. The second error is "*CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type
   'ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand<System.Reactive.Unit,
   System.Reactive.Unit>' to 'ReactiveUI.ReactiveCommand'*"

How can I use the command pattern in this MVVM code sample with ReactiveUI v13.0.38?

Comment: We removed the non generic ReactiveCommand. You use Unit as a generic type like the answer has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReactiveCommand`](https://www.reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/reactivecommand_2/) class which implements `ICommand` interface is a generic type.

```
// Unit is used for void - no input and output, so double Unit
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ParameterlessCommand { get; }

// assigning
ParameterlessCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(Parameterless);
```